How to restart Android Activities with new Locale?
I've created an Android Studio Application that aims to update language of several Jetpack Compose Activity classes.
Part of the functions are moved to the helper class LanguageUtils.java:
class LanguageUtils {

    static String getCurrentLanguage(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("app_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getString("lang", "en");
    }

     static void saveLanguage(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("app_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putString("lang", language).apply();
        Log.e("MyApplication", "getCurrentLanguage: " + getCurrentLanguage(context));
    }

    static Context setLocale(Context context, String lang) {

        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration resConfig = resources.getConfiguration();
        Configuration config = new Configuration(resConfig);

        config.setLocale(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(config);

    }

}

The application itself has the following methods:
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        val currentLang = LanguageUtils.getCurrentLanguage(base)
        val newContext = LanguageUtils.setLocale(base, currentLang)
        super.attachBaseContext(newContext)
    }

    fun setAppLanguage(activity: Activity, language: String) {

        LanguageUtils.saveLanguage(activity, language)

        val intent = activity.intent
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        activity.startActivity(intent)
        activity.finish()

    }

}

What I want to achieve is to trigger resource update in the activity by pressing a button
(I use XML resources located in folders res/values for English and res/values-** for other languages and use them with stringResource(R.string.someString)). How to do this on Android?
I used a button inside my activity like this:
val context = LocalContext.current
Button(
  modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
  onClick = {
     val app = context.applicationContext as MyApplication
        val activity = context as Activity
        app.setAppLanguage(activity, "pl")
  }
) { Text("Change to Polish") }

When I run this code, the activity is restarted (the visible swipe animation) but the texts remain in English.
It's also worth noting that updateConfiguration() is marked as deprecated by Android Studio from API 25 (Android 7) and therefore I don't want to use it

You don't need to restart activity, it is triggered by your change. Use LocaleManager and/or AppCompatDelegate together with LocaleListCompat  https://github.com/dmitrish/Jetpack-Compose-Android-History-Calendar-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/coroutines/thisdayinhistory/MainActivity.kt

What worked for me was to move MyApplication.attachBaseContext() to the activities and then use either recreate() or startActivity() + finish() to reload the activity.

Just call activity.recreate() to trigger the configuration update:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#recreate()

It could be how you are calling your activity to restart with the usage of flags.
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP If your activity is already in the stack, it clears all activities above it and calls onNewIntent() instead of re-creating the activity.
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK It creates a new task if the activity isn't already running in the current task. But when combined with CLEAR_TOP, the focus shifts to the task stack management rather than ensuring a fresh activity instance.
You can use other combination Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.
By using only CLEAR_TASK and NEW_TASK together:

You guarantee the stack is cleared.

The activity is completely restarted, ensuring that onCreate() runs and all resources (including locale changes) are refreshed.



Thanks for the explanation! For my specific case (loading language-specific files from the app files directory) it turned out that I must use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, while removing FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP didn't really change anything. This is a very nice explanation.
